# Calculating Mathematical operations using Closures...?

Tags: javascript, closures

It is not showing result by user selection please give me help

It is a calculator operator using a closure function

in the result block it is showing as a NaN after converting it to an Integer also.

Mathamatical.js //closure content

```
var pradeep=(function(){
    result = 0; sum_is=sub_is=mul_is=divn_is=0; 
    function manupulation(x,y){
        sum_is = getsumValues(x,y);
        sub_is = getsubValues(x,y);
        mul_is = getmulValues(x,y);
        divn_is = getdivnValues(x,y);
        return result[sum_is,sub_is,mul_is,divn_is];
    }
    function getsumValues(x,y){
        var sum_is = x+y;
        return result[0]; 
    }
    function getsubValues(x,y){
        var sub_is = x-y;
        return sub_is;
    }
    function getmulValues(x,y){
        var mul_is = x*y;
        return mul_is;
    }
    function getdivnValues(x,y){
        var divn_is = x/y;
        return divn_is;
    }return{
        manupulation_value : function(x,y){
            return manupulation(x,y);
        }
    }
})();
```

My second js file

```
function calculate_operations(){
    var details = {}
    details.Firstvalue = document.querySelector("#fnumber").value;
    details.SecondValue = document.querySelector("#snumber").value;
    details.Firstvalue = parseInt(details.Firstvalue);
    details.SecondValue = parseInt(details.SecondValue);
    details.result = 0;
    //details.selectedOperation = document.querySelector("operation")
    details.showdetails = function(){
        console.log(pradeep);
        document.querySelector("#numberF").innerText = details.Firstvalue;
        document.querySelector("#numberS").innerText = details.SecondValue;
        function operationsMathematical(){
            if (document.querySelector("#operation".value == "")) {
                document.querySelector("#sel_operation").innerText = +"No operation selected";
            }
            if (document.querySelector("#operation").value== "add") {
                document.querySelector("#sel_operation").innerHTML =+details.Firstvalue +"+" +details.SecondValue ;
                details.result= pradeep.manupulation_value(details.Firstvalue,details.SecondValue);
                //console.log(details.Firstvalue,details.SecondValue);
                details.result=parseInt(pradeep.manupulation_value(result[0]));
                document.querySelector("#result_block").innerHTML = +details.result;

            }
            if (document.querySelector("#operation").value== "sub") {
                document.querySelector("#sel_operation").innerText =+details.Firstvalue  +"-" +details.SecondValue;
                details.result=pradeep.manupulation_value(result[1]);
                document.querySelector("#result_block").innerHTML = +details.result;
            }
            if (document.querySelector("#operation").value== "mul") {
                document.querySelector("#sel_operation").innerText =+details.Firstvalue +"*" +details.SecondValue;
                details.result= pradeep.manupulation_value(details.Firstvalue,details.SecondValue);
                details.result=parseInt(pradeep.manupulation_value(result[sum_is]));
                document.querySelector("#result_block").innerHTML = +details.result;
            }
            if (document.querySelector("#operation").value== "divn") {
                document.querySelector("#sel_operation").innerText =+details.Firstvalue +"/" +details.SecondValue;
            }
        }
        operationsMathematical();
    }
    //details.result= pradeep.manupulation_value(details.Firstvalue,details.SecondValue);
    document.querySelector("#showvalues").style.display="block";
    details.showdetails();
}
```

Comment: What do you think `return result[sum_is,sub_is,mul_is,divn_is];` does given that `result` is `0`? What it *actually* does is return `undefined`; you probably meant `return [sum_is,sub_is,mul_is,divn_is];` to return an array with the results in it. Your `getSumValues()` function has a similar issue. (So the problem isn't with the closure...)

Comment: In `getsumValues` you are returning `result[0]` even though `result = 0` (it is a number, not an array)

Comment: Thank you.... Even Though it is showing an error that sum_is not defined while returning the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed file. This should work

```
var pradeep=(function(){
    // No need of these variables result = 0; sum_is=sub_is=mul_is=divn_is=0; 
    function manupulation(x,y){
        var sum_is = getsumValues(x,y); //use var otherwise global scope is used
        var sub_is = getsubValues(x,y);
        var mul_is = getmulValues(x,y);
        var divn_is = getdivnValues(x,y);
        return [sum_is,sub_is,mul_is,divn_is];
    }
    function getsumValues(x,y){
        var sum_is = x+y;
        return sum_is; 
    }
    function getsubValues(x,y){
        var sub_is = x-y;
        return sub_is;
    }
    function getmulValues(x,y){
        var mul_is = x*y;
        return mul_is;
    }
    function getdivnValues(x,y){
        var divn_is = x/y;
        return divn_is;
    }
    return{
        manupulation_value : function(x,y){
            return manupulation(x,y);
        }
    }
})();
```

Your second file has errors.

```
    function calculate_operations(){
        var details = {}
        details.Firstvalue = document.querySelector("#fnumber").value;
        details.SecondValue = document.querySelector("#snumber").value;
        details.Firstvalue = parseInt(details.Firstvalue);
        details.SecondValue = parseInt(details.SecondValue);
        details.result = 0;
        //details.selectedOperation = document.querySelector("operation")
        details.showdetails = function(){
            console.log(pradeep);
            document.querySelector("#numberF").innerText = details.Firstvalue;
            document.querySelector("#numberS").innerText = details.SecondValue;
            function operationsMathematical(){
                if (document.querySelector("#operation".value == "")) {
                    document.querySelector("#sel_operation").innerText = +"No operation selected";
                }
                if (document.querySelector("#operation").value== "add") {
                    document.querySelector("#sel_operation").innerHTML =+details.Firstvalue +"+" +details.SecondValue ;
                    details.result= pradeep.manupulation_value(details.Firstvalue,details.SecondValue);
                    //console.log(details.Firstvalue,details.SecondValue);
                    details.result=parseInt(pradeep.manupulation_value(result[0]));
                    document.querySelector("#result_block").innerHTML = +details.result;

                }
                if (document.querySelector("#operation").value== "sub") {
                    document.querySelector("#sel_operation").innerText =+details.Firstvalue  +"-" +details.SecondValue;
                    details.result=pradeep.manupulation_value(result[1]);
                    document.querySelector("#result_block").innerHTML = +details.result;
                }
                if (document.querySelector("#operation").value== "mul") {
                    document.querySelector("#sel_operation").innerText =+details.Firstvalue +"*" +details.SecondValue;
                    details.result= pradeep.manupulation_value(details.Firstvalue,details.SecondValue);
                    details.result=parseInt(pradeep.manupulation_value(result[2]));
                    document.querySelector("#result_block").innerHTML = +details.result;
                }
                if (document.querySelector("#operation").value== "divn") {
                    document.querySelector("#sel_operation").innerText =+details.Firstvalue +"/" +details.SecondValue;
details.result=pradeep.manupulation_value(result[3]);
                document.querySelector("#result_block").innerHTML = +details.result;
                }
            }
            operationsMathematical();
        }
        //details.result= pradeep.manupulation_value(details.Firstvalue,details.SecondValue);
        document.querySelector("#showvalues").style.display="block";
        details.showdetails();
    }
```

Comment: Even Though its not Working. Showing an error that sum_is is not defined